# How to send SNMP traps with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, snmp

In my application I have been asked to send error codes via SNMP traps. I believe that this will need to be done using version 3 because of the security issues with versions 1 and 2. Is there anything in the .net framework to do this or should I be looking to buy a third party library.

Answer (score 3):

There's an excellent open source C# library called [SharpSnmpLib](http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/).  You could read the [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1157.html) as an introduction.

I don't think anybody bothers with v3 security; it's hard enough to get it working with just community security :)

Comment: SharpSnmpLib does say it supports v3, so its still a viable option if v3 is a requirement.

Comment: An update. #SNMP 6 finally fills the gaps and fully supports v3 TRAP and INFORM messages besides v1 TRAP, v2 TRAP and INFORM. http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/releases/view/46604