# How to send a message on SNMP trap protocol from C# app?

Tags: c#

How to send a message on SNMP trap protocol from C# app?

What's the best way to do that and how? someone did it before and can give me instructions please?

I have looked around the net for a guide in c#, but I found nothing. I would like to have an easy to understand explanation of how to do it.

Whenever someone clicks on a button or does something important, I just want to be able to write a log entry for it. So, really all I need is an example on how you send entries.

I don't have any example code of what I already did because I found nothing that I can show off. I hope that i don't break the rules of this site by not showing any code already. But believe me, I tried to look around the net for it.

Thanks a lot for your help guys!

Comment: so, you swear that you couldn't find anything, right ? lol

Comment: Has already been asked: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043452/how-to-send-snmp-traps-with-c>